# Getting AJAX data in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm pulling my hair out here. I cannot access data submitted through an Ajax request in Laravel. I've tried using `formData` and just plain objects. Every time I just see a default `Request` object in Laravel and not the data I've submitted.

Here's my JS (TypeScript):

```
$('#save-section-order').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   let $this = $(this);
   let data = [];

   const order = $('#sortable').sortable('serialize');
   const project_id = $this.data('id');
   const url = "/admin/save-new-order";
   const csrfToken = $this.data('csrf');

   $.ajax({
       url: url,
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
           order: order,
           project_id: project_id
       },
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       headers: {
           'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken,
           'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH'
       },
       success: function( msg ) {
           if ( msg.status === 'success' ) {
               $this.parent().parent().fadeOut();
           }
       },
       error: function( data ) {
           if ( data.status !== 200 ) {
               $this.parent().parent().css('background-color', '#f2dede');
           }
       }
   });
});
```

Here's my web route:

`Route::patch('/admin/save-new-order', 'Admin\ProjectsController@saveSectionsOrder');`

Here's my ProjectsController:

```
public function saveSectionsOrder(Request $request) {

    dd($request);

}
```

The output is always a generic `Request` object and I cannot retrieve the data I submitted through `$request->order` or `$request->input('order')`.

I know I'm missing something really obvious, but I just can't see what.

Comment: Have you tried `dd($request->all());` ? What's the output ?

Comment: Are you sure `order` in your JS actually has data?

Comment: Try removing `contentType: false,` as well?

Comment: @ChrisForrence That did it! They were both holdovers from my attempts at using `formData`. Sigh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `contentType: false`, which tells $.ajax that you have no content.

[Per docs (emphasis mine):](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for
>   most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to  $.ajax(),
>   then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). **As of
>   jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content
>   type header.** Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that
>   the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force
>   the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests,
>   setting the content type to anything other than
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain
>   will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the
>   server.

Change that to something more appropriate, or remove it to allow it to default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Also, you may want to keep `processData: false`, depending on the nature of the data you're sending, but otherwise remove that, too.

Answer (score 0):

For receiving data from request object you must use

```
$request->all()
```

This command will get you array of passed data. Or you can access directly by name:

```
$request->input('order')
```

Comment: The question states that they are unable to get the data using `$request->input('order')`.

Comment: ahh! remove in $.ajax processData: false. Just remove it

Comment: Removed `processData: false`. Output from `$request->input('order')` and `$request->input('project_id')` is null :(

Comment: Aha! I also needed to remove `contentType: false`. Both were holdovers from my attempts at doing it with `formData`

Comment: yes, right! i saw my code and in ajax i dont have this lines